# How to compare two computers

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a way of comparing two systems. We have an issue with one of them that appears to be identical to the other. Looking for a way to scan any tiny differences between them to help us track down the cause of the issue.

We have looked at SysCompare which looks ideal, but for the odd use isn't a financially viable option. We've tried the free version and everything matches.

Are there any windows tools for this sort of thing ? Is there an industry standard method for this sort of thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really feels like overkill, but the most reliable way I can think of to do this would be to run a md5sum of both systems - [hashdeep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) looks like it would do it. md5 sums are nearly unique (that is to say, hash collisions are pretty uncommon, and while its possible to fake a hash, in this case, its unlikely)

On the other hand, it might make more sense to start with the issue, and work your way down. than checksum *all* the things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion we'll keep this as a backup. We are working through the issue logically but are starting to exhaust avenues of investigation it's boutique highly customised software so we're on our own their. Was really hoping for something that would check through registry settings, services, installed applications, etc. We'll keep this idea as a backup in case we don't find anything else.

Comment: ahh, there's no one thing that might do this. I'll update my answer, when I have time to get a test rig up but its more of a process than a single tool.